# verify scroller button works with preloaded data with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, watir

I am trying to verify that a scroller button is working correctly. The button is an arrow image that slides a row of images/links, showing 5 out of the 10 images that are all loaded at page load. Whats making it difficult is that images are populated from a 3rd party provided so the urls change all the time. The only other identifier is by its class and text, the class is the same for all of them.

Since they are all loaded at the same time its hard to determine if the images are changing.

If you go to http://www.hayneedle.com/product/curiousgeorgepeelstickgiantmural.cfm and scroll to "Suggestions For You" you can see the on the right to scroll to a new set of suggestions. This button has broke before so need a simple way to regression it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an image is actually visible to the user by using the `present?` method. You could also use the `visible?` method, but it throws an exception if the element does not exist. You can see a comparison of these and the `.exists?` method in the blog post, ["Checking for an element – exists?, visible?, present?"](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/checking-for-an-element-exists-visible-present/).

Knowing this, you could click the scrolling arrow and then check if last image is present (ie actually visible).

```
# Go to the page
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'http://www.hayneedle.com/product/curiousgeorgepeelstickgiantmural.cfm'

# This is the scroller control
scroller = browser.div(:id => 'HN_PP_RelatedCats')

# (optional) Check that the last image is *not* displayed
puts browser.div(:class => 'HN_Scroller_Cont').link(:index => 9).present?
#=> false

# Click the right scroller
scroller.div(:class => 'HN_Scroller_R').click

# Check that the last image is displayed
puts browser.div(:class => 'HN_Scroller_Cont').link(:index => 9).when_present.present?
#=> true
```

Note that the check for the last link/image is using `when_present.present?`. The `when_present` allows the scrolling to finish. Without it, you might end up checking the element before the scrolling is done (ie you false negative). The `present?` is there to return a true/false result.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the help. I was first trying to use visible? but was having some issues, this is much better.